# Error: no such file or directory, ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, files, nano

I do follow turorial at https://serverfault.com/questions/550276/how-to-block-internet-access-to-certain-programs-on-linux. But when i create file in step 2: nano /home/username/.local/bin/no-internet, it warning: no such file or dir. I tried to it with touch command but it still error: no such file or dir. what happen? Can you guide me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people document install procedures, they often want a way to refer to the installing user's `HOME` directory. In this case, he/she used `/home/username/...`, when `$HOME/.local/bin/no-internet` or `~/.local/bin/no-internet` would have been clearer.

Replace `username` with YOUR username (it is stored in the environment variable `USER`), and

```
nano /home/$USER/.local/bin/no-internet
```

or use the `HOME` environment variable to refer to your home directory ( this is better than using `/home/$USER`, since user home directories are not required to be in `/home`.

```
nano $HOME/.local/bin/no-internet
```